# Root mean log squared error issue with scitkit-learn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a Kaggle competition [(data here)](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nyc-taxi-trip-duration/data), and I am having trouble using scikit-learn's GradientBoostingRegressor. The competition is using the root mean log squared error (RMLSE) to evaluate predictions.

---

For the sake of an MWE, here is the code I used to clean the `train.csv` at the link above:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", index_col=0)

train.pickup_datetime = pd.to_datetime(train.pickup_datetime)
train["pickup_month"] = train.pickup_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.month)
train["pickup_day"] = train.pickup_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.day)
train["pickup_hour"] = train.pickup_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
train["pickup_minute"] = train.pickup_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.minute)
train["pickup_weekday"] = train.pickup_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
train = train.drop(["pickup_datetime", "dropoff_datetime"], axis=1)
train["store_and_fwd_flag"] = pd.get_dummies(train.store_and_fwd_flag, drop_first=True)

X_train = train.drop("trip_duration", axis=1)
y_train = train.trip_duration
```

---

To illustrate something that *works*, if I use a random forest, then the RMSLE is computed just fine:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


def rmsle(predicted, real):
    sum=0.0
    for x in range(len(predicted)):
        p = np.log(predicted[x]+1)
        r = np.log(real[x]+1)
        sum = sum + (p - r)**2
    return (sum/len(predicted))**0.5

rmsle_score = make_scorer(rmsle, greater_is_better=False)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1839, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)
rf_scores = cross_val_score(rf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring=rmsle_score)
print(np.mean(rf_scores))
```

This runs just fine. **However**, the gradient boosting regressor throws `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log`, and I get a `nan` from the `print` statement. Looking at the array of three RMSLE scores, they are all `nan`.

```
gb = GradientBoostingRegressor(verbose=2)
gbr_scores = cross_val_score(gb, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring=rmsle_score)
print(np.mean(gbr_scores))
```

I assume this is because I'm getting a negative value at some place where I shouldn't be. Kaggle told me it was encountering zero or non-negative RMSLE, as well, when I uploaded my predictions there to see if it was something about my code. Is there a reason why gradient boosting cannot be used for this problem? If I use `mean_squared_error` as the scorer (`mse_score = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)`), it returns that just fine.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple about gradient boosting; why is this scoring method *not* working for the gradient boosting regressor?

Comment: (I'm also primarily an R user, so if someone has Python critique of the code in general, please share, if you'd like).

Comment: You could add `print(predicted)` in the `rmsle` function to check if there are negative values in the predicted array. Btw, the `for` loop in the `rmsle` function could be written as `np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power(np.log(np.array(predicted)+1) - np.log(np.array(real)+1), 2)))` which should be faster than looping through the arrays.

Comment: @σηγ bingo, that's it. Thanks! And thanks for the vectorized code for the score, as well.

Comment: Mark were you able to use this new scorer for fitting? With RandomizedSearchCV it does not work whatever I do. If I set greater_is_better=False, it's negating it and starts minimizing negated value. If greater_is_better=True, it's maximizing the loss, both are wrong. What to do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the syntax that make_scorer takes for your function is of the following form:

```
def metric(real,predictions)
```

Not

```
def metric(predictions,real)
```

So you will need to print `real` values in your code to get the actual `predicted` values for your regressor.

Just change the function as follows and it should work correctly:

```
def rmsle(real, predicted):
    sum=0.0
    for x in range(len(predicted)):
        if predicted[x]<0 or real[x]<0: #check for negative values
            continue
        p = np.log(predicted[x]+1)
        r = np.log(real[x]+1)
        sum = sum + (p - r)**2
    return (sum/len(predicted))**0.5
```

Secondly, You regressor is giving a wrong value at predcition for row no. 399937 in the first cross-validated set. Hope this helps ! All the best for your competition.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you to vectorize this

```
def rmsle(y, y0):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(np.log1p(y) - np.log1p(y0))))
```

Benchmarks can be found here

https://www.kaggle.com/jpopham91/rmlse-vectorized